# Representation consultation django

Tags: django, orm

How could represent this query in Django ORM?

```
select RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(06), COUNT(*)+1), 6) as Codigo from bd_pago
```

Comment: What do you mean with represent ?

Comment: MyModel.objects.raw( )